# What is the meaning of "PO"?

Tags: slang, abbreviations

I encountered a sentence, "My parents were so POed when I got into this." when I was watching an anime show. What does PO stand for? I guess its meaning is something like angry but have no idea what it is from. I googled it but found nothing.

Comment: It means pissed off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'[Pissed off](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/pissed+off)', meaning annoyed or angry. It can also be written as P-ed Off (spoken as 'peed off').

Comment: I'd be tempted to write 'PedO', because 'POed' looks like 'piss offed', but then I guess 'PedO' looks kind of unfortunate, especially in American spelling zones.